# Hugging Face Transformers BART CUDA error: CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZE

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, text-classification, huggingface

I'm trying to finetune the Facebook BART model, I'm following [this article](https://huggingface.co/transformers/v3.2.0/custom_datasets.html#seq-imdb) in order to classify text using my own dataset.

And I'm using the Trainer object in order to train:

```py
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir=model_directory,      # output directory
    num_train_epochs=1,              # total number of training epochs - 3
    per_device_train_batch_size=4,  # batch size per device during training - 16
    per_device_eval_batch_size=16,   # batch size for evaluation - 64
    warmup_steps=50,                # number of warmup steps for learning rate scheduler - 500
    weight_decay=0.01,               # strength of weight decay
    logging_dir=model_logs,          # directory for storing logs
    logging_steps=10,
)

model = BartForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("facebook/bart-large-mnli") # bart-large-mnli

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,                          # the instantiated  Transformers model to be trained
    args=training_args,                   # training arguments, defined above
    compute_metrics=new_compute_metrics,  # a function to compute the metrics
    train_dataset=train_dataset,          # training dataset
    eval_dataset=val_dataset              # evaluation dataset
)
```

This is the tokenizer I used:

```py
from transformers import BartTokenizerFast
tokenizer = BartTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('facebook/bart-large-mnli')
```

But when I use `trainer.train()` I get the following:

Printing the following:

```py
***** Running training *****
  Num examples = 172
  Num Epochs = 1
  Instantaneous batch size per device = 4
  Total train batch size (w. parallel, distributed & accumulation) = 16
  Gradient Accumulation steps = 1
  Total optimization steps = 11
```

Followed by this error:

```py
RuntimeError: Caught RuntimeError in replica 1 on device 1.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/parallel_apply.py", line 61, in _worker
    output = module(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1130, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/models/bart/modeling_bart.py", line 1496, in forward
    outputs = self.model(
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1130, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/models/bart/modeling_bart.py", line 1222, in forward
    encoder_outputs = self.encoder(
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1130, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/models/bart/modeling_bart.py", line 846, in forward
    layer_outputs = encoder_layer(
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1130, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/models/bart/modeling_bart.py", line 323, in forward
    hidden_states, attn_weights, _ = self.self_attn(
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1130, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/models/bart/modeling_bart.py", line 191, in forward
    query_states = self.q_proj(hidden_states) * self.scaling
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1130, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py", line 114, in forward
    return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
RuntimeError: CUDA error: CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED when calling `cublasCreate(handle)`
```

I've searched this site and GitHub and hugging face forum but still didn't find anything that helped me fix this for me (I tried adding more memory, lowering batches and warmup, restarting, specifying CPU or GPU, and more, but none worked for me)

#### Databricks Clusters:

- **Runtime:** 12.2 LTS ML (includes Apache Spark 3.3.2, GPU, Scala 2.12)
  **Worker Type:** Standard_NC24s_v3 with 4 GPUs, 2 to 10 workers, I think 16GB RAM and 448GB memory for the host
- **Runtime:** 12.1 ML (includes Apache Spark 3.3.1, Scala 2.12)
  **Worker Type:** Standard_L8s (Memory optimized), 2 to 10 workers, 64GB memory with 8 cores

**Update:** With the second cluster, depending on the flag combination, I sometimes get the error `IndexError: Target {i} is out of bounds` where `i` change from time to time

> If you require any other information, comment and I'll add it up asap

---

My dataset is holding private information but here is an image of how it's built:
[image: dataset image]

---

### Updates:

I also tried setting the:

- `fp16=True`
- `gradient_checkpointing=True`
- `gradient_accumulation_steps=4`

Flags but still had the same error when putting each separately and together

##### Second cluster error (it get this error only sometimes, based on the flag combination):

```py
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
File <command-2692616476221798>:1
----> 1 trainer.train()

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:1527, in Trainer.train(self, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval, **kwargs)
   1522     self.model_wrapped = self.model
   1524 inner_training_loop = find_executable_batch_size(
   1525     self._inner_training_loop, self._train_batch_size, args.auto_find_batch_size
   1526 )
-> 1527 return inner_training_loop(
   1528     args=args,
   1529     resume_from_checkpoint=resume_from_checkpoint,
   1530     trial=trial,
   1531     ignore_keys_for_eval=ignore_keys_for_eval,
   1532 )

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:1775, in Trainer._inner_training_loop(self, batch_size, args, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval)
   1773         tr_loss_step = self.training_step(model, inputs)
   1774 else:
-> 1775     tr_loss_step = self.training_step(model, inputs)
   1777 if (
   1778     args.logging_nan_inf_filter
   1779     and not is_torch_tpu_available()
   1780     and (torch.isnan(tr_loss_step) or torch.isinf(tr_loss_step))
   1781 ):
   1782     # if loss is nan or inf simply add the average of previous logged losses
   1783     tr_loss += tr_loss / (1 + self.state.global_step - self._globalstep_last_logged)

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:2523, in Trainer.training_step(self, model, inputs)
   2520     return loss_mb.reduce_mean().detach().to(self.args.device)
   2522 with self.compute_loss_context_manager():
-> 2523     loss = self.compute_loss(model, inputs)
   2525 if self.args.n_gpu > 1:
   2526     loss = loss.mean()  # mean() to average on multi-gpu parallel training

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:2555, in Trainer.compute_loss(self, model, inputs, return_outputs)
   2553 else:
   2554     labels = None
-> 2555 outputs = model(**inputs)
   2556 # Save past state if it exists
   2557 # TODO: this needs to be fixed and made cleaner later.
   2558 if self.args.past_index >= 0:

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1190, in Module._call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1186 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1187 # this function, and just call forward.
   1188 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1189         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1190     return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1191 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1192 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/models/bart/modeling_bart.py:1561, in BartForSequenceClassification.forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, decoder_input_ids, decoder_attention_mask, head_mask, decoder_head_mask, cross_attn_head_mask, encoder_outputs, inputs_embeds, decoder_inputs_embeds, labels, use_cache, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
   1559 elif self.config.problem_type == "single_label_classification":
   1560     loss_fct = CrossEntropyLoss()
-> 1561     loss = loss_fct(logits.view(-1, self.config.num_labels), labels.view(-1))
   1562 elif self.config.problem_type == "multi_label_classification":
   1563     loss_fct = BCEWithLogitsLoss()

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1190, in Module._call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1186 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1187 # this function, and just call forward.
   1188 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1189         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1190     return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1191 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1192 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py:1174, in CrossEntropyLoss.forward(self, input, target)
   1173 def forward(self, input: Tensor, target: Tensor) -> Tensor:
-> 1174     return F.cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight,
   1175                            ignore_index=self.ignore_index, reduction=self.reduction,
   1176                            label_smoothing=self.label_smoothing)

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:3026, in cross_entropy(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction, label_smoothing)
   3024 if size_average is not None or reduce is not None:
   3025     reduction = _Reduction.legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce)
-> 3026 return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index, label_smoothing)

IndexError: Target 11 is out of bounds.
```

The number 11 changes from time to time.

Comment: You should check if you are running out of memory and thus cannot create a cublas handle anymore

Comment: The GPU memory and not the host RAM

Comment: I tried, I also tried using stuff from [here](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/en/perf_train_gpu_one) but still with no luck of solving this error

Comment: Have you tried your code on a CPU too? or a different GPU cluster (if possible, with some sort of optimization?)

Comment: Yes I tried on a CPU cluster and also on an optimized memory cluster, same errors usually, besides 1 time (I will update the question accordingly)

Comment: Can you please post the full error message when you train on your CPU cluster? Can you please also add a small (artificial) sample of your data and your preprocessing steps?

Comment: I added the second error that I get sometimes

Comment: The model you are using only has 3 labels. Therefore you get an error when one of your samples defines `11` as a target. Load your model with: `model = BartForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("facebook/bart-large-mnli", ignore_mismatched_sizes=True, num_labels=NUM_UNIQUE_LABELS)` and try it again.

Comment: I would appreciate if you can look at my next problem question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76170604/huggingface-pipeline-with-a-fine-tuned-pre-trained-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76170604/huggingface-pipeline-with-a-fine-tuned-pre-trained-model)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your problem, here is how I solved it (on both of the clusters you provided).

In order to solve it I used (at the `from_pretrained` call):

- `ignore_mismatched_sizes=True`: because the model you use has fewer labels than what you have
- `num_labels={}`: Insert the number of your labels, I used 16 just to be sure

> It's based on both your errors but mainly the second one, I suspect it was also the source of the second error on the GPU, please test and confirm it

I also used the following (at the `TrainingArguments` call for memory optimizations):

- `fp16=True`
- `gradient_checkpointing=True`

I tested it with up until `num_train_epochs=12`, `per_device_train_batch_size=16`, `per_device_eval_batch_size=64`, `warmup_steps=500`
and it worked just fine, hopefully, it will help you get the desired results.

> You can look at the 2 final links I provided for more details about how to optimize the speed and memory while training on both GPU and CPU

For reference:

- [Huggingface Models (search for `ignore_mismatched_sizes`)](https://huggingface.co/transformers/v4.10.1/main_classes/model.html)
- [Huggingface Configuration (search for `num_labels`)](https://huggingface.co/transformers/v2.9.1/main_classes/configuration.html)
- [Fine-tuning with custom datasets](https://huggingface.co/transformers/v3.2.0/custom_datasets.html)
- [Efficient Training on a Single GPU](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/perf_train_gpu_one)
- [Efficient Training on CPU](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/perf_train_cpu)