# Problems while fine tuning facebook/bart-large-mnli

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, huggingface

I have followed the instructions given  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76213873/how-to-finetune-a-zero-shot-model-for-text-classification/76213874#76213874)  to prepare my data.

The shape of my data after transformation is as follows:
`{'label': 2,  'input_ids': [0, 44758, 3457, 13, 5, 1263, 829, 31, 5, 1263, 8401, 4001, 438, 34, 5, 511, 7390, 2, 2, 713, 1246, 16, 4287, 92, 3457, 4, 2],  'attention_mask': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],  input_sentence': '<s>Create tests for the response received from the response whihc has the following format</s></s>This example is Add new tests.</s>' }`

Rest of it is standard Huggingface model creation code:

```
from sagemaker.huggingface import HuggingFace
distribution = {'smdistributed':{'dataparallel':{ 'enabled': True }}}

model_name='facebook/bart-large-mnli'
# hyperparameters, which are passed into the training job
hyperparameters={#'epochs': 1,
                 #'train_batch_size': 8,
                 'do_train' : True,
                 'do_eval' : True,
                 'model_name':model_name,
                 'task_name': 'mnli',
                 
                 'output_dir': '/opt/ml/model',
                  
                 'overwrite_output_dir' : True
                 }

git_config = {'repo': 'https://github.com/huggingface/transformers.git','branch': 'v4.26.0'}

 
# creates Hugging Face estimator

huggingface_estimator = HuggingFace(
  
    entry_point='run_glue.py',
    source_dir='./examples/pytorch/text-classification',
    instance_type='ml.p3dn.24xlarge',
    instance_count=1,
    role=role,
    git_config=git_config,
    transformers_version='4.26.0',
    pytorch_version='1.13.1',
    py_version='py39',
    hyperparameters = hyperparameters,
        distribution = distribution
)
 

huggingface_estimator.fit({'train': training_input_path, 'test': testing_input_path})
```

**The problem is it generates a 158GB model.tar.gz whihc takes 5 hours to upload to s3!!**

Any solutions?

I have tried adding:

```
    save_strategy= "no",

    save_total_limit=1,
    load_best_model_at_end=True
```

to the model params, but it still does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The tar.gz process takes more time to upload. You can disable compression by setting compression type to None in outputDataConfig. Please refer below link

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_OutputDataConfig.html

Also if you want to save checkpoints during training you can write to /opt/ml/checkpoints and configure the necessary checkpoint configurations in the estimator. Anything written to checkpoints in directly streamed to s3 and SageMaker wont wait till the end of training to upload.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/model-checkpoints.html