# How can I perform title prediction?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I am working on creating a title on the basis of sentence using python bert-base-uncased model. Here is the code that I have written. I need to predict a title on the basis of `possible_labels`. Is there any possible way in which I can perform the title prediction on the basis of `possible_labels`?

Load pre-trained BERT model and tokenizer for text classification

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification
import torch
model_name = "bert-base-uncased"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name)
```

Define class labels

```
possible_labels = [
    "Greeting",
    "Farewell",
    "Expression of Gratitude",
    "Apology",
    "Request",
    "Command or Instruction",
    "Advertisement or Promotion",
    "News Update",
    "Question",
    "Positive Sentiment",
    "Negative Sentiment",
    "Neutral Statement",
    # Add more labels as needed
]
```

Input sentence to classify

```
text = "working on work"

# Tokenize and encode the input sentence
encoded_input = tokenizer(text, return_tensors="pt")

# Make a prediction
output = model(**encoded_input)

# Get the predicted class index
predicted_class_index = torch.argmax(output.logits, dim=1).item()

# Get the predicted label
predicted_label = possible_labels[predicted_class_index]
```

Print the results

```
print("Input Sentence:", text)
print("Predicted Label:", predicted_label)
```

Print all probabilities

```
probabilities = torch.nn.functional.softmax(output.logits, dim=1).tolist()[0]
for label, prob in zip(possible_labels, probabilities):
    print(f"Probability for {label}: {prob:.4f}")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will not work because the head of the model you want to use is untrained. You also receive a message when you execute your code:

> Some weights of BertForSequenceClassification were not initialized
> from the model checkpoint at bert-base-uncased and are newly
> initialized: ['classifier.bias', 'classifier.weight'] You should
> probably TRAIN this model on a down-stream task to be able to use it
> for predictions and inference.

The two obvious options you have are:

1. Finetune your model with your data. Follow this guide for further instructions: [guide](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/tasks/sequence_classification).
2. Switch to zero-shot classification. The first section of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76213874/6664872) explains the underlying concept. All you need to do is loading a `nli` or `zeroshot` model via pipeline:

```py
from transformers import pipeline

possible_labels = [
    "Greeting",
    "Farewell",
    "Expression of Gratitude",
    "Apology",
    "Request",
    "Command or Instruction",
    "Advertisement or Promotion",
    "News Update",
    "Question",
    "Positive Sentiment",
    "Negative Sentiment",
    "Neutral Statement",
    # Add more labels as needed
]

# maybe try other models
pipe = pipeline("zero-shot-classification", model="facebook/bart-large-mnli")

pipe("working on work", candidate_labels=possible_labels)
```

Output:

```
{'sequence': 'working on work',
 'labels': ['Question',
  'Request',
  'Positive Sentiment',
  'Neutral Statement',
  'Command or Instruction',
  'News Update',
  'Negative Sentiment',
  'Advertisement or Promotion',
  'Expression of Gratitude',
  'Apology',
  'Farewell',
  'Greeting'],
 'scores': [0.17385907471179962,
  0.15512266755104065,
  0.1200760081410408,
  0.11586172878742218,
  0.08471532166004181,
  0.0735798180103302,
  0.0702444538474083,
  0.06881491094827652,
  0.04482586681842804,
  0.0351007916033268,
  0.03142492100596428,
  0.026374489068984985]}
```